# What is the monospace font used in Postman? (screenshot attached)

Tags: font-identification, monospace

What is the font that is in this screenshot?

[image: screenshot from Postman]

I've tried using font-identifying tools with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: In my own attempts to figure it out, the letters seem very similar to Courier. Some  distinctions between this and Courier are the slashed zero and the slant in the #-symbol.

The 'l' and ';' are also very distinctive from Courier.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to tell us which identification tools you've used?

Comment: Compare select characters against the list in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming. Look at the `l` (ell, not `1` or `I`) and `0`; these seem fairly distinct.

Comment: I believe postman currently uses Cousine. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The font is very similar to a thinner version of **PT Mono** in the
>   Google web fonts.

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/PT+Mono

[image: Pt Mono Google webfont]

> **And this is a version from Font Squirrel:**

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/pt-mono

[image: PT Mono font squirrel]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, however as I have stumbled upon it, somebody else could too. Today, the Postman desktop app uses **IBM Plex Mono** as its' monospaced font. Hope this helps.

Here's the link to the website: https://www.ibm.com/plex/

Since Postman is a web app, they allow you to use the browser's DevTools to inspect elements:

[image: Inspect Element Console]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score -4):

Its open sans its a free font. https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Comment: No, it most certainly is not Open Sans. It looks nothing like Open Sans—it’s not even a sans-serif font.